# Store reference to a object

Tags: c#, reference

I have to store reference to an object so that any updates to the value of the object will take place whenever that reference is dereferenced. A simple example is

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace ABCD
{
    public class ClassA<T>{
        T t;
        public T func(T num){
            t = (T)(object)(2*(double)(object)num);//t has to be assigned in this method (not in func2)
            T x = func2();
            t = (T)(object)(3*(double)(object)num);//t will be reassigned here, and I want this to be reflected in x
            return x;//I want x to be 9 not 6
        }
        public T func2(){
            return t;
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClassA<double> a = new ClassA<double>();
            System.Console.WriteLine(a.func(3.0));
        }
    }
}
```

So `func` should be returning `ref T` instead of `T`, and in `Main` method when I would deref the return value of `a.func()`, I would be able to get expected answer. How can I make this happen in C#?

The requirement mentioned in code comments cannot be changed but if you have a better solution please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

```
using System;

namespace ABCD
{
    public class ClassA<T>
    {
        T t;
        public T func(T num)
        {
            t = (T)(object)(2 * (double)(object)num);//t has to be assigned in this method (not in func2)
            ref T x = ref func2();
            t = (T)(object)(3 * (double)(object)num);//t will be reassigned here, and I want this to be reflected in x
            return x;//I want x to be 9 not 6
        }
        public ref T func2()
        {
            return ref t;
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClassA<double> a = new ClassA<double>();
            Console.WriteLine(a.func(3.0));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) keyword marks something as a reference, which is exactly what you need here.

To use the `ref` keyword, you have to add it on the left (so that the compiler knows that it is a reference you store) and on the right side (of course you have to assign a reference to a reference) of an assignment, and in a method it has to be in the method header (the type of the method must be a reference, because you want to use it as a reference later) and in the return statement (because you have to return the correct type). A reference can be dereferenced by simply assigning it without the `ref` keyword.

Comment: I am not good in C# but your example does not compile. http://rextester.com/PNXRI65492  Please check.

Comment: @JaneDorothy This seems to be a problem of rextester - if you compile it for example with Linqpad it works: http://csharppad.com/gist/11e494cc65b43ad5fd90cb273c8e629c - I'd suggest to use VS anyway, as online compilers are good for short code testing, but not for real programming.